# Getting rid of an unwanted space between 2 divs

Tags: css, html

I have searched google, but I didn't find anything. I searched this site and found this topic [Unwanted space between divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349724/unwanted-space-between-divs) which seems similar, and i have tried to apply

```
margin:0px;
```

several places, but there i still, space between the two divs.

Heres my html

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>title/title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="e.css">
</head>


<body>

<div id="page">

    <div id="content">
        <div id="up">
            <div id="tab">
                  <ul id="tabmenu">
                <li id="anm" class="tbs blue"><a href="#"><span>Anm</span></a></li>
                <li id="kom" class="tbs blue"><a href="#"><span>Kom</span></a></li>

                <li id="omt" class="tbs blue"><a href="#"><span>Omt</span></a></li>
                <li id="sts" class="tbs blue"><a href="#"><span>Sts</span></a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="usrp">
            <div id="usr">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="bottom">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Css

```
html {
    height: 98%;
}

body {
    height:99%;
}

#page {
    height:99%;
}

#content {
    /*border:2px solid blue;*/

}

#bottom {
    border:2px solid green;
    height:15%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#up {
      /*border:dotted green 2px;*/
      width:59%;
}

.usrcom {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted blue;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:15px;
}

#usrp {
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    border-right: 2px solid blue;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;

    border-bottom:2px solid blue;
    border:dotted yellow 2px;


}

/***Tabs menu*****/
#tabmenu {
  float:left;
  width:685px;
  /*background:#BBD9EE;*/
  /*background:#FF6633;*/
  font-size:93%;
  line-height:normal;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;

  /*border:dotted red 2px;*/
  border-bottom:2px solid blue;
  /*border:dotted red 2px;*/


}

#tabmenu ul {
  /*background:#BBD9EE;*/
  padding:0px 0px 0 0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
  border:dotted green 2px;
}

#tabmenu li {
  display:inline;
  padding:0;
  margin:0px;
}

#tabmenu a {
  float:left;
  /*background:url("img/tableft2.png") no-repeat left top;*/
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0 4px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#tabmenu a:hover span {
background-color:#3399FF;
margin:0px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}

#tabmenu a span {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  /*background:url("img/tabright2.png") no-repeat right top;*/
  padding:5px 15px 4px 5.5px;
  margin:0px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#0000FF;

  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

I can find out why the space happens, how can I solve this unwanted space.

Edit:

Ups, yearh, forgot to tell which divs,

It is between 'Tabmenu' and 'usrp'

Edit:

Tried to apply in my css

```
#tab {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
```

}

For it is in really between 'tab' and 'usrp' but that does no help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/AhHvu/ Which divs are you talking about?

Comment: Which 2 div? You got a few of them there.

Comment: Updated to tell which, divs its between, It is between 'Tabmenu' and 'usrp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS:

```
#tabmenu {
  margin:0; 
}
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to use an inspector and "inspect this element". Then you can hover over all the elements on your page and literally see their margins/paddings, and what CSS is causing them. You can even edit CSS on-the-fly to test out a fix before applying it. My preference is the Firebug add-on for Firefox, but Chrome, Safari, and even Internet Explorer all have them built in now.